# why is there a dash in front of zsh (-zsh) if I echo $0 in zsh?

Tags: shell, zsh

If in **bash** I do (from the command line)

```bash
echo $0
```

the output is

```
bash
```

and similarly in other shells.

But if I do the same in **zsh** the output is

```
-zsh
```

Why is there that dash in front of zsh?

Comment: is zsh your login shell?

Comment: @glennjackman its my login shell and on mac I get the same -zsh

Comment: The leading dash is an old convention; invoking a shell using a name that begins with `-` indicates that it is a login shell (essentially, equivalent to `zsh -l`). Your terminal emulator is following that convention.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An old convention among shells is that if the shell is invoked using a name that starts with `-`, it should initialize itself as a login shell. Your terminal emulator is following this convention when it executes `zsh` for you.

You can observe this using the `-l` flag to `zsh`'s built-in `exec` (which adds a leading `-` to the name of the command).

```
% ( exec bash -c 'echo $0')
bash
% ( exec -l bash -c 'echo $0')
-bash
```

The effect of the leading `-` is generally equivalent to running the shell with the `-l` option.

Comment: POSIX [`exec`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#exec) has no options.  Bash [`exec`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-exec) does — I hadn't looked before to see if it does.  You could also have used `exec -l` to add the dash before `bash`, it seems.

Comment: The user indicate `zsh` was their login shell, so it was safe to assume `exec -a` was available for demonstration purposes, to show how the value of `$0` could be set. (I wasn't aware of `-l`, though. That is simpler.)